# POSIX and Portability | shell scripts | grep -s, grep -q

Tags: shell-script, grep, scripting, posix, portability

I am all in for portability in regards to shell scripts.

But I am unsure if I am overdoing it right now.

In this example, we have a function called `confirmation`, which accepts the very first argument as a string containing a question, and all of the other arguments are to be possible valid answers:

---

```bsh
confirmation ()
{
    question=$1; shift; correct_answers=$*

    printf '%b' "$question\\nPlease answer [ $( printf '%s' "$correct_answers" | tr ' ' / ) ] to confirm (Not <Enter>): "; read -r user_answer

    # this part iterates through the list of correct answers
    # and compares each as the whole word (actually as the whole line) with the user answer
    for single_correct_answer in $correct_answers; do
        printf '%s' "$single_correct_answer" | grep -i -x "$user_answer" > /dev/null 2>&1 && return 0
    done

    return 1
}

confirmation 'Do you hate me?' yes yeah kinda
```

---

As you can see, the core part is utilizing `grep`, so I looked into the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep), and found this:

```
-q, --quiet, --silent
Quiet; do not write anything to standard output. Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found, even if an error was detected. Also see the -s or --no-messages option. (-q is specified by POSIX .)
-s, --no-messages
Suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files. Portability note: unlike GNU grep, 7th Edition Unix grep did not conform to POSIX , because it lacked -q and its -s option behaved like GNU grep's -q option. USG -style grep also lacked -q but its -s option behaved like GNU grep. Portable shell scripts should avoid both -q and -s and should redirect standard and error output to /dev/null instead. (-s is specified by POSIX .)
```

Let's stress this part:

> Portability note: unlike GNU `grep`, 7th Edition Unix `grep` did not conform to [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), because it lacked `-q` and its `-s` option behaved like GNU `grep`'s `-q` option. USG-style `grep` also lacked `-q` but its `-s` option behaved like GNU `grep`. Portable shell scripts should avoid both `-q` and `-s` and should redirect standard and error output to `/dev/null` instead.

---

Am I overdoing it already, or is the redirection to `/dev/null` the only portable way?

---

I **am not** concerned about portability to an operating system version from forty years ago!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unix V7 was released in the late 70s. That's the version that introduced the Bourne shell.

However, at that time, function support hadn't been added yet, `read` didn't have `-r`, there was no `printf` command. Case insensitive `grep` was with `grep -y`. And of course `$(...)` is not Bourne.

Unix-like systems have evolved quite a bit since then and diverged. In the early 90s POSIX did attempt to bring some unification back.

There are still however systems that haven't followed POSIX in their default implementations, only adding the POSIX-compliant implementations as separate utilities.

For instance, the `/bin/grep` of Solaris is closer to the V7 `grep` than to the POSIX `grep`. The POSIX `grep` on Solaris is in `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` (not available in minimal deployments of Solaris).

`/bin/grep` on Solaris has no `-q`, `-E`, `-F`.

When working on Solaris, you generally want to put `/usr/xpg4/bin` at the front of `$PATH` and use `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/sh` (though that changed in Solaris 11, where /bin/sh is now ksh93, so on average more POSIX compliant than the very buggy ksh88-based `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`).

Some other portability comments on your code:

- The behaviour of `correct_answers=$*` or `read -r` depends on the current value of `$IFS`. (`$*` joins the positional parameters with the first character of `$IFS`, `read` uses `$IFS` to split the input into words), so you'll want to set it to the value you want.

  By joining the positional parameters into a scalar string, that means it won't work properly if any of them contain the separator, unless you use NL as the separator as anyway `read` will only read one line so the answer cannot contain a newline.
- you're including into the `%b`-formatted arguments things that are probably not meant to have `\x` sequences expanded.
- `for single_correct_answer in $correct_answers` uses split+glob. I don't think you want the glob part here, and again it's a bit silly to do a join to later split it again (unreliably).
- `grep -i -x "$user_answer"` does a regex pattern matching as opposed to a case insensitive comparison. Also, it won't work properly if the answer starts with `-`, as `grep` would then take it as an option.
- `printf '%s' text` produces non-text output (missing newline), so the behaviour of `grep` on it is unspecified (and in practice non-portable).

So, with those in mind, I would change the code to:

```
confirmation()  {
    question=$1; shift

    printf '%s\nPlease answer [' "$question"
    sep=
    for answer do
      printf %s "$sep$answer"
      sep=/
    done
    printf '] to confirm (Not <Enter>): '
    IFS= read -r user_answer

    # this part iterates through the list of correct answers
    # and compares each as the whole word (actually as the whole line)
    # with the user answer
    for single_correct_answer do
      printf '%s\n' "$single_correct_answer" |
        grep -ixFqe "$user_answer" && return
    done

    return 1
}
```

Comment: The ksh88 based ksh in /usr/xpg4/bin is closer to the POSIX standard than ksh93. Shells in general have various problems and none of the available shells is good enough to be named as the POSIX shell of the year.

Comment: @schily, `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` has countless bugs and deviations from the standard including major ones, all-in-all probably fewer than ksh93, see for instance the (long) discussion at https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg01603.html (to which you took part).

Comment: Well, I would be happy if there was one shell that is completely compliant but this is not available yet. The sad news for ksh93 is that there is no acceptable new maintainer since David did stop working on it.